# like запрос mysql

Tags: php, mysql

здравствуйте, к примеру есть запрос:

```
where var LIKE %var% AND var1 LIKE %var1%
```

можно ли как то отсортировать результат по количеству совпавших слов? что то на подобии ORDER by LIKE'S MATCH

Comment: like ищет одно совпадение в строке и останавливается. поэтому вам надо использовать либо полнотекстовый поиск, вместо like. либо делать словарь, где все слова будут лежать отдельными записями, связанными с основной таблицей и тогда, конечно можно будет дать like, сгруппировать и отсортировать по количеству

Comment: Это что, ещё и поиск ведётся в нескольких полях? ну так, судя по тексту запроса...

Comment: а что за полнотекстовый поиск?

Answer (score 0):

Ну чисто теоретически (дурь, конечно):

```
SELECT   (var LIKE @var) + (var1 LIKE @var1) /* + ... */ AS OverlapsCount,
         `table`.*
FROM     `table`
HAVING   OverlapsCount >= @MinTemplatesCount
ORDER BY OverlapsCount DESC
```